# Updating Portal Item Thumbnail ONLY if it is has not been changed yet using ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api, thumbnail

Using Python, is it possible to check if the thumbnail for a Portal Item is the default thumbnail? I want to update thumbnails if they have not been updated yet.

I know I can update thumbnails using the update function:
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html?highlight=update#arcgis.gis.Item.update

```
myPortal = GIS("myportal.com", "username", "password")
itemToUpdate = myPortal.content.get("item ID number")

#item_properties below would be a dictionary of portal properties to update
itemToUpdate.update(item_properties, thumbnail = "myNewThumbnailPath")
```

Essentially, I'd like to change all the thumbnails of items that are using the default image to my own thumbnail, leaving the items that already have a different thumbnail unchanged. Of course, I'd rather not check the 100+ items manually.